# AngularJS smart-table: How to use buttons to setup pre-defined filters for data?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using `smart-table` plugin for AngularJS to display a collection information. I have integrated the same with my backend API using the `stPipe` function which is triggered whenever a `search` or `sort` operation is performed. However, I want to place some buttons above the table which act as a filter. When I click on either of these buttons, I want to trigger the `stPipe` function of smart table and hit the backend API to fetch the filtered results. How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to put the table state in a controller variable.

Everytime the callServer function is called, it will update this variable. This way, you will be able to refresh the table.

In this code, the callServer would be your stPipe function and your external button would call the refreshGrid() function.

```
this.tableState = null;

this.callServer = function callServer(tableState) {
    ctrl.tableState = tableState;
    ...
}

this.refreshGrid = function(){
    ctrl.callServer(ctrl.tableState);
}
```

I needed this before and I have posted the solution in this question: [Smart table - angularJs - ajax refresh table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768988/smart-table-angularjs-ajax-refresh-table)